# Appending scripts from view helper method not working in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have a view helper method which is like this

```
class Zend_View_Helper_LoginForm extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function loginForm()
    {
        $script = "<script type='text/javascript'>(function (){ $('#submit').click(function (){alert('hello'); return false;})})</script>";     
        $this->view->headScript()->appendScript($script, $type = 'text/javascript');
        $login = new Application_Form_User();
        return $login;
    }

}
```

But this is not working. I also tried

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl('/js/jquery.js'), 'text/javascript');
```

but this is not working either. If i try this code in layout.phtml  then it works.Any Idea?

Comment: It should work. Are you calling <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?> in your layout ?

Comment: yes i am sure i have called this in my layout.phtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view file:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('your/sript/file.js') ?>
```

In your layout:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript() ?>
```

Comment: I cannot append this file in view file because this script is for a common plugin that all views share

Answer (score 0):

You have to add setView method:

class My_View_Helper_ScriptPath
{
    public $view;

```
public function setView(Zend_View_Interface $view)
{
    $this->view = $view;
}

public function scriptPath($script)
{
    return $this->view->getScriptPath($script);
}
```

}